# Bug in downcase-region when using cua-set-rectangle-mark?

Tags: rectangle

Is the following a bug or a feature?  If the former, how do I file?  If the latter, can someone explain the logic?

On the following content in my buffer (*scratch*), upon marking the inner rectangle consisting of "FG" and "JK" using C-return

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

Applying `downcase-region` yields the following unexpected result:

```
ABCD
Efgh
ijKL
MNOP
```

I would expect "fg" and "jk" to be downcased, and not "fgh" and "ij".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me.  But it might be an enhancement request: have commands such as `downcase-region` act on a rectangle region.

In either case, use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report it (you can use your own email client to send the info, if you like). The Emacs developers will let you know whether it is a bug or an enhancement request (or neither).

Comment: Thanks, added bug [#20070 have commands such as downcase-region act on a rectangle region](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20070).

Comment: Yup, I saw it. Thx.